# Reusing a thread for multiple functions and events in C++(basically POSIX thread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

I have to design a threadhandler in posix in such a way is that a single thread will be dedicated for handling a function and event. For events I will create a queue and thread and push the event to the queue. But how will I engage same thread for handling functions. Should I use same queue for function as well?? If so how will I pass function in it??

Please help or correct if I am putting the question in wrong way.

Comment: "thread for handling a function"? Please explain in detail or with an example.

Comment: Only keywords for online search: What about function pointers? What about the command pattern?

Comment: Lets say I have 1 event DOOR_OPEN and a method start_exam(). So the object which does some job on event and the method start_exam should go in a same thread. For event I don't see any difficulty here but how the method start_exam will be handed over to the same thread?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "event" as it can mean different things and there's no clear meaning of "event" in C++

Comment: @Chris use your queue to push 'tasks' to your thread; as long as you take care and put those tasks in some structure that suits both needs, nothing stops you from sending both events and "functions" to the thread. PS:why do you need this?

Comment: @HAL I believe that Chris wants a mini-thread-pool where functions are tasks / kitchen sink thread that does it all.

Comment: @Jonathan upon receiving an event it will call a certain method which is mapped with the event. Event is just an enum data type.

Comment: OK, enum is what I was looking for. As other comments say, look at the _Command_ design pattern. You want to encapsulate a task in an object and push that object onto the queue.

Comment: @bkdc On a concrete way I can form the sentence like " for my object I need a dedicated thread which serve some events and functions". The same thread must be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave another comment but I need the space...

Not valid C but you get the idea:

```
struct task //could use an union
{
    int type; //0 if task is event, 1 for "function", etc...consider using enums
    int ev;
    std::function<void()>> func;
};
std::queue<task> pending;
```

....
in your thread:

```
auto t = pending.front();
pending.pop();
if(t.type==0)//we have an event to process
{
   proc_event(t);
}
else if(t.type==1)//run a function
{
   t.func();
}
```

good luck with exception handling and make sure that one of your functions doesn't kill the thread or blocks it for too long